# How can you obtain the items within a group inside a PagedCollectionView?

Tags: .net, wpf, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

I have a PagedCollectionView, but the Groups property on it doesn't expose any information about each group, such as which of the items in the PagedCollectionView are within that group, which is information I need to know..

I'd like to do something like this:

```
(System.Windows.Data.CollectionViewGroupInternal)pcv.Groups[0].Items;
```

It seems that this is held within an internal class, and is not obtainable from client code. Is there another way to get this information?

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that this simple feature is completely impossible using the public interfaces of the DataGrid. Simply amazing that this basic feature has been missing for years in this grid.